# Spring hibernateTemplete get not getting updated record value

Tags: spring, hibernate

When process is in execution a stored proc is called using Java standard callable statement, which updates the record in db.
Later in flow, using hibernatetemplate get method(passing entity Id object), instance of record is fetched.
The problem is this instance has old value for record columns, before update by stored proc happened.
Its probably happening because hibernateTemplalte was called earlier for same table to update the same record. But even then, if get method is called shouldn't it make a fresh call to db to get updated record.
I tried using flush, but still issue remains.
Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try using Session.refresh() on the entity?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes i tried refresh, flush all of them.Now i am trying to execute session SQL query and getting the updated value, using hibernate SQLQuery api.